# "could not determine data type of parameter $1" with Postgres

Tags: spring-jdbc

I am facing this seem to be famous issue by setting a timestamp binding against postgres.

```
@Test
public void testGetCurrentDate() {

    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasources.get(dbType));

    PlatformTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasources.get(dbType));

    final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System
            .currentTimeMillis());

    new TransactionTemplate(manager).execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            template.update("create table test_timestamp (col timestamp)", Collections.emptyMap());
            template.update("insert into test_timestamp (col) values (:TS) ", Collections.singletonMap("TS", ts));
        }
    });

    Assert.assertEquals((Integer) 1, new TransactionTemplate(manager).execute(new TransactionCallback<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            MapSqlParameterSource paramsSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            paramsSource.addValue("TS", ts, Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");

            return template.queryForObject("select 1 from test_timestamp where :TS is not null and col=:TS ", paramsSource,
                    Integer.class);

        }
    }));

}
```

This test fails with **ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1**

See here the discution with postgres about that:
http://www.postgresql-archive.org/quot-could-not-determine-data-type-of-parameter-quot-with-timestamp-td5995489.html

I already have a workaround for that (Setting a PGTimestamp instance instead of Timestamp). I was wondering if it is something that could benefits to Spring JDBC to increase portability accross multiple databases.

In this case the workaround would be something like this in org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils ( around line 380):

```
else if (sqlType == Types.TIMESTAMP &&
"PostgreSQL".equals(ps.getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName()))) {

            Class<?> pgTimestampClass = Class.forName("org.postgresql.util.PGTimestamp");
            Timestamp ts = (Timestamp)pgTimestampClass.getConstructor(long.class).newInstance(javaValue.getTime());
            ps.setTimestamp(paramIndex, ts);
```

If you think that it something that makes sense, I could propose a pull request.

Arnaud

Comment: This a question about the validity of a feature request. It belongs in the issue tracker of the relevant project.

Comment: You tagged this with spring-data-jdbc. But it doesn't seem to relate to spring-data-jdbc, but to spring-jdbc. Both have their issue tracker here: https://jira.spring.io/issues/ Spring Jdbc is part of Spring Framework.